# How to find the maximum likelihood estimators of parameters in the Pareto distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Here's the Pareto distribution:

$$F(x; \theta_1, \theta_2) = 1 -  \Big(\frac{\theta_1 }{x}\Big)^{\theta_2}, \qquad \theta_1 \le x, \qquad \theta_1, \theta_2 > 0$$

I have been trying to solve the maximum likelihood for this, but it is complicated and so is its logarithm. I tried many things but in vane. How does one show this?

Comment: You ought to have $F$ rather than $f$, i.e. the expression to the right of the "equals" sign is the c.d.f. rather than the p.d.f. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Indeed, I patched it up for the OP so that the answer, which is worth the time reading, is at least to a correctly posed question.

Answer (score 27):

Note that the definition of the Pareto distribution you are using is the cumulative distribution function, whereas in maximum likelihood estimation you need to use the probability density function, which for the Pareto distribution is given by
$$f(x;\alpha,\beta) = \alpha {\beta^{\alpha}\over x^{\alpha+1}}, \qquad x \geq \beta, \quad \alpha,\beta > 0. $$
Compared to your equation, $\theta_1 = \beta$ and $\theta_2 = \alpha$.

The likelihood function of the Pareto distribution given a sample $x=(x_1,\dotsc, x_n)$ is given by
$$\mathcal{L}(\alpha,\beta;x)=\prod\limits^n_{i=1}\alpha{\beta^\alpha\over x_i^{\alpha+1}}=\alpha^n \beta^{n\alpha}\prod\limits^n_{i=1}{1\over x_i^{\alpha+1}}. $$
Taking the log of the likelihood, we obtain
$$\ln[\mathcal{L}(\alpha,\beta;x)] \equiv \ell(\alpha,\beta;x)=n \ln (\alpha) + n\alpha \ln(\beta) - (\alpha+1)\sum\limits^n_{i=1}\ln(x_i). $$
Since a higher $\beta$ will always result in a higher likelihood$—$$\ln(\beta)$ is monotonically increasing$—$we maximize the likelihood by setting $\hat{\beta}$ as high as possible. Since $\beta \leq x_i$ for all $i$, we maximize the likelihood by setting $\hat{\beta} = \min\limits_i x_i$, the smallest $x_i$ in the sample.

For $\alpha$, we set the partial derivative of $\ell$ with respect to $\alpha$ equal to $0$:
\begin{align}{\partial \ell(\alpha,\beta) \over \partial \alpha} &= {n\over \alpha}+n \ln(\beta)- \sum\limits^n_{i=1}\ln(x_i)=0.\end{align}
Therefore,
$$\hat{\alpha}= {n \over \sum\limits^n_{i=1}\ln(x_i)-n\ln(\hat{\beta}) }. $$
I hope this helps.

Comment: I would divide that $n$ through to make clearer the connection to sample means

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on how to find $\hat{\beta}$. I'm trying to solve this problem as I type this message.

Comment: We try to maximize the (log-)likelihood function, but a higher $\beta$ will always yield a higher likelihood (there is no maximum) so we can’t use differentiation to maximize the likelihood in this case. However, we know by definition that every observation $x_i$ is greater than or equal to $\beta$, so $\beta$ cannot be greater than the smallest observed value. Therefore we set $\hat{\beta} = \min_i x_i$.

Comment: @MichaelChirico What connection to the sample mean do you have in mind?

Comment: @littleO $\hat{\alpha} = \frac1{\frac1{n} \sum \limits_{i = 1}^n \ln r_i}$ where $r_i$ is the ratio of each observation to the minimum observation, $r_i = \frac{x_i}{\hat{\beta}}$. Not _the_ sample mean ($\frac1{n} \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n x_i$) but a sample mean nonetheless

Comment: @molarmassThanks for your answer (not my question). But is there a way we can approximate the sampling distribution of $\hat{\alpha}$ at least for large sample size $n?$ The things coming to mind are first to find the distribution of each $ln(X_i),$ the if we try to use the strong law of large numbers, it's going to converge a.s. to a suitable constant. But I've a HW question that just asks to approximate the distribution of $\hat{\alpha}$ without stating anything about the sample size. How do we proceed?